# How to pass data into state using ReactJS and AmChart

Tags: reactjs, amcharts

I created a web application  that shows reports using amChart and followed the ReactJS amChart implementation, now i am trying to pass the firebase query result into ReactJS state, but cannot feature out why i cannot get the state data value to appear.

My idea is to sum all expense data and profit data then setState each of it and then pass it to amChart chart.data array

My code so far.

```
  componentDidMount () {

        am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

        let chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
        let expense = 0;
        let profit = 0;
       
        const citiesRef = db.collection('transactions');

        // Create a query against the collection
        const queryRef = citiesRef.where('category', '==', 'Expense').get();
        const queryProf = citiesRef.where('category', '==', 'Profit').get();
        
         queryRef.then(ref=> {

              ref.docs.forEach(doc => {

               expense += parseInt(doc.data().amount)
               
              
              })
              
              return this.setState( { totalExpense: expense } )
         })

         queryProf.then(ref=> {
            ref.docs.forEach(doc => {

             profit += parseInt(doc.data().amount)
             
            
            })
           
            return this.setState( { totalProfit: profit } )
       })
         
       chart.data = [ 
            {
                "year": "2003",
                "expense": this.state.totalExpense,
                "profit": this.state.totalProfit,     
            }
        ];
             
        
        // Rest of the chart code..
       
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `setState` is asynchronous, you will never get the results this way.

You need to characterize your `componentDidMount` method as `async componentDidMount` and then `await` for the promises to finish

`await queryRef.then(ref=> {`

and

`await queryProf.then(ref=> {`